# Calling parameterized stored procedure in OpenQuery - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, openquery

I am calling a stored procedure in `OpenQuery` and passing parameters to the stored procedure.

```
declare @Src nvarchar(max),@Tgt nvarchar(max)
declare @sql_str nvarchar (4000)
set @Src = '$\VMT\Versions\0900\AMS\'
set @Tgt = '$\VMT\Versions\0900\Base\'
set @sql_str = 'exec [Tfs_VMT Collection].dbo.MergeCandidate ''' + @Src+ ''' , ''' +@Tgt+''' ' 
set @sql_str = 'select * into #test from openquery(ODSSERVER,''' +Replace(@sql_str,'''', '''''') +''')'

print @sql_str

EXEC (@sql_str)
```

but this fails with following error

> Msg 7357, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot process the object "exec [Tfs_VMT
>   Collection].dbo.MergeCandidate '$\VMT\Versions\0900\AMS\' ,
>   '$\VMT\Versions\0900\Base\' ". The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for
>   linked server "ODSSERVER" indicates that either the object has no
>   columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

I have checked this has nothing to do with permissions.

Can you please help?

Comment: So you are tried GRANT EXEC on this stored proc and this is not helped?

Comment: Can you take the value of Print @sql_str and run it successfully?

Comment: is the sp_serveroption 'DATA ACCESS' set to True?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the exec from your openquery query. You should be able to just pass in the procedure name/parameters.

```
set @sql_str = '[Tfs_VMT Collection].dbo.MergeCandidate ''' + @Src+ ''' , ''' +@Tgt+''' '
```